# Вопрос об использовании @ (собаки в синтаксисе)

Tags: php, laravel

Я новичек в ооп и только приступаю к изучению laravel.

Суть вопроса:

Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');

Как я понял у нас идёт обращение к методу index класса UserController.
Но насколько я знаю обращение к методам класса в php осуществляется через два двоеточия ::

В доках php про эту собаку ничего не нашел. Это какая-то специфика самого Laravel или это всё таки из php?

Comment: Это специфика Laravel.

Comment: Непонятно почему вы сразу стали читать документацию PHP и не стали читать документацию по Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers

Answer (score 3):

сама по себе собака в пхп [используется для подавления вывода ошибок](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). Но в данном случае у вас собака внутри строкового литерала, поэтому значит она не более чем просто символ собаки. Очевидно, в дальнейшем используется для разделения имени контроллера и экшена.

Comment: Ответ очень несильно связан с вопросом

Comment: @tutankhamun ответ отвечает именно на тот вопрос, какой автор задал. Расписывать тут для чего собака эта используется во всех аспектах laravel смысла нет. Приведен конкретный пример с маршрутизацией, дан конкретный ответ, что он в примере означает.

Comment: я в курсе для чего нужна собака в php. суть вопроса в том что laravel без обьяснений начинает собственную компиляцию. вроде идёт стандартный php и не с того не с сего предлагается собственный синтаксис про который ни где не написано - просто сказано делай вот так. и это сильно путает

Comment: @trancenergy2 вы привели пример с роутингом. Если речь про шаблоны blade, то про это и спрашивайте. Шаблоны они обрабатываются и на их основе строится готовый пхп код. Про синтаксис шаблонов читайте в соответствующих разделах документации. шаблоны это не чистый пхп.

Comment: Шаблоны-то тут при чем?

Comment: @tutankhamun наверное при том, что там можно увидеть использование конструкций `@section`, `@yield` и т.п.?